# Access. История движения

Tags: ms-access

Суть: нужно отслеживать историю движения материальных ценностей. Таким образом, чтобы нажимая на позицию в режиме таблицы, разворачивалась история её движения (и возможность добавлять историю).

Я создал отдельную таблицу, в которую по средствам подстановки и отношений будут попадать данные и всё выглядит тип-топ. Позицию можно развернуть и добавлять в неё данные

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема заключается в том, что введённые данные находятся внутри позиции до момента закрытия Access. После повторного открытия файла, все введённые данные уходят в конец таблицы. Как я могу это исправить?
Так же, буду рад, если мне предложат более лучший вариант ведения такой базы.

Comment: *введённые данные находятся внутри позиции до момента закрытия Access. После повторного открытия файла, все введённые данные уходят в конец таблицы.* Вот совершенно непонятная формулировка. Записи по умолчанию сортируются в соответствии с первичным индексом. Нужна другая сортировка, скажем, по штампу времени создания записи? ну так указывайте её в свойствах формы или её источника данных явно.

Answer (score 0):

[@Akina](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/229437/akina):

Записи по умолчанию сортируются в соответствии с первичным индексом. Нужна другая сортировка, скажем, по штампу времени создания записи? ну так указывайте её в свойствах формы или её источника данных явно.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]